# simple_form collection checkboxes add unexpected values to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, collections, simple-form

Environment: Rails 3.2.1
SimpleForm 2.0.1
I have encountered users here and elsewhere asking similar questions via Google, but I have not yet found answers!

I want to provide a series of checkboxes to define a contact's preferences.
I made a small test app using something I noticed on the simple_form demo app.

My Contact model has a string attribute named "post_pref"

In ContactsHelper I included this:

```
def contact_preference_options
  ['High Resolution','Web Resolution','Browser','Hard Copy Proof']
end
```

In my _form partial I include this:

```
<%= f.input :post_pref, :collection => contact_preference_options, :as => :check_boxes %>
```

I started the server and created a new Contact.

In the New and Edit views, the checkboxes show up. I checked "Browser" as a preference for my new Contact and submitted it.
The result of checking one or several preferences is a mess.

First:
when I go to edit a record, the current preferences aren't checked.

Second:
In the Show and Index views I see this:

```
--- - Browser - ''
```

In the console, I see this:

```
---\n- Browser\n- ''\n
```

What I *want* to see is this:

```
Browser
```

My questions are:
Where are the dashes coming from?
Where are the new lines coming from?
Why is there an empty string?
Why aren't the previously selected checkboxes checked when I edit a Contact?

Note: when I did the above with radio buttons or select options it works fine. But I want the contact to potentially have several preferences so I need checkboxes.

Interestingly, I tried the same thing with formtastic instead of simple_form and got almost identical results. What's the trick for checkboxes?

Thanks a million for any help.

Answer (score 0):

For me it looked like it was saving the array, so I did some preprocessing of the parameters before saving it:

```
lifestyle = params[:lifestyle]
lifestyle[:languages] = lifestyle[:languages].reject(&:blank?).join(",")
if @lifestyle.update_attributes(lifestyle)
...
```

In this example, my checkboxes was languages under the lifestyle model. Hope this helps.